Is there any way to access the digital signature inside a MailItem from Outlook VSTO?
I'm trying to extract the signed data object from mailItem created by Outlook in OnSent event to add an extra signed attribute. Is there any way to extract and update the signed data, but also to make sure that Outlook will not delete my custom signed attribute?
I've tried to take a look using Outlook Spy on the properties exposed and Redemption to convert the message into SecureMailMessage, but the problem is that there is no EntryId set. And, on top of that, how do I recreate the mailItem and make sure that the message format wasn't somehow affected.

You cannot modify the signed data in any way - that is the whole point of signing/encrypting a message. But the message being sent in Application.ItemSend is not encrypted yet, and you should be able to add any extra properties. Keep in mind however, that all MAPI specific properties will stripped out since they cannot be converted to MIME format.

What I've tried yesterday was to update the content of the RDOAttachment but after this, when I export the msg is looks like is corrupted.

Can you be more specific? What is the relevant snippet of yoru code? How does the corruption manifest itself?

item.SaveAs("C:/Users/Public/test.msg");
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
RDOMail msg = session.GetMessageFromMsgFile("C:/Users/Public/test.msg");
RDOAttachment attachmentt = msg.Attachments[1];
byte[] content  = attachmentt.AsArray;
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms();
signedCms.Decode(content);
var attr = GetAttribute();
signedCms.SignerInfos[0].SignedAttributes.Add(attr);
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = new("C:\\Users\\Public\\smime.p12","pass");
CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(x509Certificate2);
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
byte[] newSignData = signedCms.Encode();
var base64SignedData = Convert.ToBase64String(newSignData);
attachmentt.AsText = base64SignedData;
attachmentt.AsArray = newSignData;
attachmentt.Save();
msg.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\Public\\resignedTest.eml", rdoSaveAsType.olRFC822);


So to provide more context: item is a MailItem from Outlook VSTO OnItemSend event and after I run the code, at save throws the error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Error in IMessage.OpenAttach: MAPI_E_NO_ACCESS'. I cannot somehow bypass this?
